# Keep only rows where one column is minimal

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-delete

I am looking for an SQLite query to vastly reduce the irrelevant noise in my database.
The relevant table contains pairs of points (‘hexbin’s), together with the distance between them and the source that gave this distance. I'd like to keep only the rows for the minimum distance found in any source for every pair of points.

I think

```
DELETE FROM dist
  WHERE hexbin1, hexbin2, source NOT IN (
    SELECT hexbin1, hexbin2, source FROM dist INNER JOIN (
      SELECT hexbin1 as h1, hexbin2 as h2, min(distance) as m
      FROM dist GROUP BY hexbin1, hexbin2)
    ON hexbin1==h1 AND hexbin2==h2 AND distance==m);
```

should do roughly the right thing.
In theory, I can have different rows that have the same hexbin1, hexbin2 and distance, but different source. In practice, this is unlikely and no hindrance to the next processes that need to use the database, so they can be kept or deleted depending on which is easier to do; my query above keeps the duplicates, but everything else being equal, I would prefer to keep only one arbitrary specimen from all those with the minimum distance.

Naively read, it iterates over the table three times, which sounds inconvenient. How can I do this better?

Comment: Is there a case for a combination of hexbin1, hexbin2 to have duplicate distances so the min distance exists in more than 1 rows?

Comment: In theory, I can have different rows that have the same hexbin1, hexbin2 and distance, but different source. In practice, this is unlikely and no hindrance to the next processes that need to use the database, so they can be kept or deleted depending on which is easier to do.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT hexbin1, hexbin2, MIN(distance)
FROM dist d
GROUP BY hexbin1, hexbin2
```

returns all the min distances for each combination of `hexbin1, hexbin2`.
If there is no case of duplicate minimum distances you can use it like this:

```
DELETE FROM dist
WHERE (hexbin1, hexbin2, distance) NOT IN (
  SELECT hexbin1, hexbin2, MIN(distance)
  FROM dist 
  GROUP BY hexbin1, hexbin2
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6563aae416aa001d727e824532efb712).

But if there are duplicates then the tie breaker can be the column [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) with the help of `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
DELETE FROM dist
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT FIRST_VALUE(rowid) OVER (PARTITION BY hexbin1, hexbin2 ORDER BY distance, rowid)
  FROM dist
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=059fba8f2e2ecac4dda4d180099a0880).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
delete from dist
    where exists (select 1
                  from dest d2
                  where d2.hexbin1 = d.hexbin1 and d2.hexbin2 = d.hexbin2 and d2.distance > d.distance
                 );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(hexbin1, hexbin2, distance)`.